# PyQt5 QFileDialog setFont

Tags: python, pyqt5, qfiledialog

I have created larger program for Raspberry Pi 3+. Part of it is a method calling QFileDialog. As I am using embedded display icons are very small and I would like to increase the size of them

I only use (ShowDirsOnly) and I got 2 icons Choose and Cancel - in the documentation, it states Accept and Reject but I can't find one I got.

Here is my code:

```
dialog = PyQt5.QtGui.QFileDialog()
dialog.setLabelText(dialog.Accept,"WYBIERZ") 
dialog.setFont(PyQt5.QtGui.Font('Arial',12))
my_dir=dialog.getExistingDirectory(None,"Wybierz folder", "/media/pi/".dialog.ShowDirsOnly)
```

It doesn't work.. I have spend a lot of time on that maybe somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,\
    QFileDialog
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
dialog = QFileDialog()
dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog.DirectoryOnly)    
dialog.setLabelText(QFileDialog.Accept, "WYBIERZ")
dialog.setLabelText(QFileDialog.Reject, "REJECT")
dialog.setFont(QFont("Arial", 20))
dialog.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Key points:

[getExistingDirectory](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getExistingDirectory) is a static function. Do not mix it up with a QFileDialog instance. You need to set `DirectoryOnly` by `dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog.DirectoryOnly)`

[QFileDialog::Accept](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#DialogLabel-enum) and [QFileDialog::Reject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#DialogLabel-enum) are enum values. You need to refer to them as `QFileDialog.Accept` and `QFileDialog.Reject` in `pyqt`.

You need to import `QFont`, not `Font`.